# cv2 tooks a very long time to update frames

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

i'm very new to python,opencv and raspberry pi in general
i want to stream the video from 2 usb webcams and use haarcascade to detect cars (toy cars).
i don't know what i'm doing wrong,i installed opencv by using pyimagesearch tutorials, please help me

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import sign
import subprocess

cascade_src = 'cars.xml'
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_src)

ip_cam=[cv2.VideoCapture(0),cv2.VideoCapture(1)]

try:
    while True:
        detected = [0,0]
        
        for ip in range(len(ip_cam)):
            
            ret,img=ip_cam[ip].read()
            img=imutils.resize(img,width=300)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 1)
            
            for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
            cv2.imshow(str(ip), img)                      
            b=str(len(cars))
            a= int(b)
            detected[ip]=a
            n,s=detected
            
            print("------------------------------------------------")
            
            #print ("North: %d South: %d East: %d West: %d"%(n,s,e,w))
            print ("North: %d South: %d "%(n,s))
            
            if n>=2:
                
                print ("North More Traffic")
                sign.north()
                
                
            elif s>=2:
                print ("South More Traffic")
                sign.south()
                
                
                
            else:
                #red()
                sign.normal()
                print ("no traffic")                
            
            if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
                break
                
except KeyboardInterrupt:            
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but as noted by Adrian himself on this [blogpost](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/25/raspberry-pi-face-recognition/), doing those things on the raspberry pi will be slow.

What's advised is to do the processing on your PC or laptop and just send the results back to the pi, or if you need to do it on the pi, you can resize the image even more not just the 300 width, resize it to an even smaller scale, check the documentation [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) or just use this:

```
dim = (width, height)
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

I would think trying different widths and heights until the speed is good enough.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've tried your code and changing different widths and heights and the speed is still just still slow. i guess it's just impossible with 2 cameras. thank you